# Disable let's encrypt certbot daily renew emails

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

Is it possible to tell certbot not to email me every day when running on cronjob?

My cronjob is:

```
0 0 * * * sudo /usr/bin/certbot renew --post-hook "sudo service nginx reload"
```

And I get emails:

```
Cert not yet due for renewal
```

I only want to get emailed when a certificate is up for renewal, failed to renew, or has been renewed.

I don't need to be notified daily that there is nothing to renew.

Comment: What is the from address in the email that you are receiving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Certbot user guide](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html), if you only wanted to be informed of renewal failures then you could add the `--quiet` option to your command:

```
certbot renew --quiet --post-hook "sudo service nginx reload"
```

If you only want to suppress this one particular message then you could modify your command to use `grep` to discard the message, something like:

```
certbot renew --post-hook "sudo service nginx reload" | grep -v "not yet due for renewal"
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know certbot never sends any emails, it's just a command line utility. It's letsencrypt.org who sends certificate expiration notice. But it only sends email when the certificate is about to expire for a domain whose certificate was procured using your email (by `--email` flag of certbot).

I assume there is some other custom service or script which is sending this email.

Comment: The emails are being sent by the `cron` service. `cron` runs commands according to a specified schedule on behalf of users. This is why the OP mentions "cronjobs"; he has arranged for `cron` to run the `certbot` command every day at midnight. If the execution of a scheduled command produces output, the `cron` service collects that output and emails it to the job's owner.

Comment: Oh! cool. I didn't knew that cron jobs can send status emails, I haven't used them much. I also didn't knew about the ```--quiet``` flag. 
You learn something new everyday... :)